# Search python dictionary values list without loop

Tags: list, python-2.7, search, dictionary

I have a huge dictionary (70 million keys) that is structured as such:

```
mydict[key] = [val1, val2, val3]
```

I need to put `val1` in a separate variable if I find a positive match for `val2`, and I am trying to do this without a for loop to save time. Basically, I want to do this:

```
for key, val in mydict.items():

   val1, val2, val3 = val

   if val2 == 'awesome match':

       new_var = val1
```

but I want to avoid the for loop.

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is really possible. There are different ways to iterate through the dictionary (for loop, while loop, map function), but fundamentally, if you want to check every `val2` for a match, you do actually need to check every entry in the dictionary.

Comment: Arg. I imagined as much. Thanks anyway for the quick response.

Comment: If speed is an issue, maybe switching to another type than a dictionary could help; are you handling fixed-size numerical values for your three variables?

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for `pandas`, where such queries would be optimised in C.